# Validating expiration date in php

Tags: php

I am trying to validate credit card expiry date as entered by the user in PHP. This is what I have so far:

```
if (!isset($_POST["cardDate"])) {
        header("location:payment.php");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        $cardDate=$_POST["cardDate"];

        if ($cardDate=="") {
        $err_msg .="<p>Please enter the credit card expiration date.</p>";

    }   
    else {
        if (!preg_match("/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[-][0-9]{2}$/", $cardDate)) {
           $err_msg .= "<p>The expire date format is not correct!</p>";

        }
        else {
            $currentDate = date('m/y');
            $exp = strtotime($cardDate);
            $current = strtotime($currentDate);
            if ($current>$exp) {
                $err_msg .= "<p>Credit card has expired";
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

The code currently is not working and I think it is because the user will be entering the expiry date in the "mm-yy" format and I am not sure whether the $currentDate part of the code conveys that message. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what needs to be changed in order for PHP to validate the expiry date? An example of the input date would be 05/19 or 11/20. The code will then match whether 05/19 or 11/20 has already passed by comparing it to today's date which is 05/20. The card expiry date must be after the current date. 
HTML code

```
<p><label for="cardDate">Credit card expiration date</label>
<input type="text" name="cardDate" id="cardDate" maxlength="5" size="5" required="required" placeholder="mm-yy" /></p>
```

Comment: Can you show us the example of `user input`? Is that month with leading zeroes?

Comment: @HarishST I have edited the question to include an example and my relevant HTML code.

Comment: Only Month and Year? No Date?

Comment: @HarishST yes only month and date in the mm-yy format

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using PHP DateTime class.
Please note you should strictly ensure the user input is in a valid format.

From PHP Docs:

> invert is 1 if the interval represents a negative time period and 0
>   otherwise.

```php
$userInput = '05-20'; // Example User input
$cardDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-y', $userInput);

$currentDate = new DateTime('now');
$interval = $currentDate->diff($cardDate);

if ( $interval->invert == 1 ) {

    // Expired
    echo "Expired\n";
}
else {
    // Valid
    echo "Valid\n";
}
```

Use the following documentation for more:

[PHP DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime)

Comment: This seems to only be checking the month entered and also a predefined input. What if the input is from a form and the year also needs to be checked? Do I just add another line like if ($interval->y)>0 ?

Comment: Hi, There is some mistake in the code.  I will update the answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check and let me know the result. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Thank you so much for updating your answer. It works better now. However, I have one last query. If the user enters the input 05-20 it should say that the card has expired since it is already 05-20 (May, 2020). Is there any way I can update your code to do that?

Comment: Sure? Lets say the current date is 01-05-2020 and the user enters the date 05-2020. Then should it be expired? However, I will update the code for that.

Comment: I have updated the answer to fulfilling your requirement. Now just need to check the interval is negative or positive. Please test the code and let me know.

Comment: The code still says valid when the month entered is 05-20. However, it should say expired. Basically, if the month and year the user enters is the same as the current month and year, it should say expired.

Comment: Are you sure? I have run this code and verified. It is getting expired since `$interval->invert` will  return 1 if we input current month with year. Can you show me a input where the condition fails?

Comment: when the input is 05-20, which is the current month and year, it fails and says the credit card is still valid. It should say expired.

Comment: I am getting `Expired`. Checkout this Link: https://paiza.io/projects/1u4Nv7U8Oo-uNCEVPSZF1A?language=php